# How to implement Markov-switching VAR in python?

Tags: python, vector, markov

[This is a link that shows how to implement Markov-switch AR model](http://www.chadfulton.com/topics/markov_autoregression.html#markov-switching-autoregression-models).

However, I want to extend AR model to VAR model. Anyone knows how to do it in python? I appreciate your help.

Comment: BTW, there is a MSVAR package in Ox, very old stuff...

Comment: http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/software/ox/Msvardoc.pdf

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is a msbvar package in R, but I need to be in python...